# selenium test not opening a browser django

Tags: python, unit-testing, selenium

I am trying to run a selenium test and this seems nothing happening. I tested the following code to make sure the setting was working: the firefox browser loaded as it is expected.

In functional_tests.py

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
broswer.get('http://localhost:8000')
```

But when I changed it to as follows:

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver

class NewVistorTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self): 
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.browser.quit()

    def test_can_open_browser(self):
        self.browser.get('http://localhost:8000')
        self.assertIn('Test', self.browser.title)
```

It was not opening the browser, nothing was happening. I ran this python functional_tests.py

What is the best way to organize unit tests and selenium tests. I'd like to run it by module name, not all in tests.py or test_abc.py, not by nose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you expect it to run? Python won't automatically run tests, just because they're in a class. You need to add a couple more lines to the end of your file:

```
class NewVistorTest(unittest.TestCase):
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(warnings='ignore')
```

This conditional is how a Python script checks if it has been executed from the command line, rather than just imported by another script. We call `unittest.main()` to launch the `unittest` test runner, which will automatically find test and methods in the file and run them.

Without that block, as you've seen, nothing happens.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I missed that part.